# Passing a value through method calls, which is unused until the end

Tags: ruby

I have nested method calls. During the nested method calls, a value `dataForLastStep` is created at some point, and is passed intact and unused until the final method. The methods look like this:

(dataForLastStep is calculated out of startingData in methodOne)

```
def methodOne(startingData)
  #...Doing some stuff with startingData to end up with data
  methodTwo(data, dataForLastStep)
end

def methodTwo(data, dataForLastStep)
  #...Doing some stuff with data to make dataStep3
  methodThree(dataStep3, dataForLastStep)
end

def methodThree(data, dataForLastStep)
  #...Doing some stuff with data to also dataForLastStep
  #All done
end
```

However, it doesn't seem too elegant. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: What you say a "method chain" is not what is normally referred as a method chain in the context of Ruby.

Comment: Where does `dataForLastStep` in `methodOne` come from?

Answer (score 2):

You have not made clear where `dataForLastStep` is created. I assume it is calculated out of `startingData` in `methodOne`.

One way to do it is to keep `dataForLastStep` as an instance variable instead. Then you can refer to that later remotely as long as it is called from the same instance.

```
def methodOne(startingData)
  data = some_stuff(startingData)
  @dataForLastStep = some_other_stuff(startingData)
  methodTwo(data)
end

def methodTwo(data)
  dataStep3 = still_some_other_stuff(data) 
  methodThree(dataStep3)
end

def methodThree(data)
  another_stuff(data, @dataForLastStep)
end
```

Comment: I'd probably keep all the data in instance variables instead of passing it around, not just `dataForLastStep`.

Comment: @Stefan The use of the parameter `data` in different methods refer to different values. `data` in `methodThree` is `dataStep3` in `methodTwo`. That is the tricky part.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I thought of a small class that takes the initial data (via `initialize`), stores it in an instance variable and operates on the encapsulated data via its methods (modifying it, extracting parts into other instance variables, etc).

Comment: @sawa thanks for that however as I'm reading a continuous stream of RabbitMQ messages I'll need that `dataForLastStep` to be unique for each message so not sure I can use a instance variable.